# bash- trimming the even lines in txt file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut, tr

I'd like to remove the first X characters and the last Y characters from all even lines of a file with bash.

Input:

```
1
AABBBBBCCC
2
GKDDABC
```

let X=2 and Y=3:

```
1
BBBBB
2
DD
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -v x=2 -v y=3 '0==NR%2 {$0=substr($0,x+1,length($0)-y-x)} 1' file
1
BBBBB
2
DD
```

How it works:

- `-v x=2 -v y=3`

  The `-v` options define our two variables, `x` and `y`.
- `0==NR%2 {$0=substr($0,x+1,length($0)-y-x)}`

  NR is the line counter.  When `0 == NR%2`, we are on an even line and we remove `x` characters from the start and `y` from the end.  In `awk`, `$0` is the whole line.  We replace with a substring which starts at position `x+1` and has length of `length($0)-y-x`.
- `1`

  This is cryptic shorthand for print the line.

Answer (score 3):

Gnu sed has the `~` step address operator. `2~2` means "start on line 2, match every second line".

```
x=2 
y=3 
sed "2~2{s/^.\{$x\}//;s/.\{$y\}$//}" input
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pE '$_=substr($_,'$x',-'$y')."\n" unless $. %2'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'n;s/^.{2}(.*).{3}$/\1/' file
```

or if you want to parameterize:

```
x=2 y=3
sed -r "n;s/^.{$x}(.*).{$y}$/\1/" file
```

Where `n` prints the odd lines drawing in the even lines for the substitution command.